# Поиск и замена по маске?

Tags: excel

Условно есть три столбца `A`, `B`, `C`. В первом имена в перемешку, во втором уникальный `id`, в третьем соответствующее этому `id` значение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем значениям `Вася` нужно присвоить `1`, `Петя`: `2`, `Лёша`: `3` и т.д - короче присвоить всем значениям соответствующий `id` из столбца `B`.

Comment: Что за бредовый набор тегов?

Comment: Необходимо описать задачу подробнее. Чем вы пользуетесь. Что у вас не получается.

Comment: *значениям "Вася" нужно присвоить "1"* - совершенно невменяемая фраза.

Comment: @Akina, да ладно? Всё же понятно. Мне вот набор тегов не понравился, а так я уже ответ написал.

Answer (score 0):

1. Если нумерация идёт подряд, то можно в столбце D написать формулу

   ```
   =MATCH(A1;$C$1:$C$4;0)
   ```

   Если не подряд, то

   ```
   =INDEX($B$1:$B$4;MATCH(A8;$C$1:$C$4;0);1)
   ```
2. Выделить получившиеся результат и <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>С</kbd>
   (не <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>)
3. Выделить A1 и <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
4. Нажать на стрелочку и выбрать вставку значений:

   [image: Скриншот]
5. Удалить лишние данные в столбце D.

Comment: *Нужно присвоить* - наверное,не менять. тогда п. 2, 3, 4 лишние. В *ИНДЕКС* в данном случае номер столбца можно не указывать

Comment: Хотя... В заголовке - *замена*... Видимо, я неправ и заменять все же нужно.

Answer (score 0):

**Формулы**:

```
=ПРОСМОТР(2;1/($C$1:$C$4=A1);$B$1:$B$4)
=ВПР(A1;ВЫБОР({1;2};$C$1:$C$4;$B$1:$B$4);2;)
=СУММЕСЛИ($C$1:$C$4;A1;$B$1:$B$4)
=СУММПРОИЗВ(--($C$1:$C$4=A1);$B$1:$B$4)
```

Из всех предложенных формульных вариантов самый быстрый *ИНДЕКС/ПОИСКПОЗ* (*INDEX/MATCH*), показанный *Qwertiy*.

Если поменять местами значения столбцов *В* и *С* (сначала искомое, правее - число), то достачно

```
=ВПР(A1;$B$1:$C$4;2;)
```

**Функция пользователя** (*UDF*)

```
Function AssigValue(r1 As Range, r2 As Range)
Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To r2.Cells.Count
        If r1.Value = r2(i, 2).Value Then AssigValue = r2(i, 1).Value: Exit For
    Next i
End Function
```

*Alt+F11* - вход в редактор *VBA*. Слева - окно дерева проекта. Добавить в проект общий модуль (*Insert-Module*), разместить там код.

В ячейку записать формулу:

```
=AssigValue(A1;$B$1:$C$4)
```

где *A1* - значение, которому нужно присвоить цифровой код, *$B$1:$C$4* - диапазон соответствий.

Протянуть формулу по строкам.

Если нужно заменить значения в первом столбце найденными соответствиями и список соответствий небольшой, можно обойтись **штатным инструментом**:

1) выделить столбец *А*

2) *Ctrl+H*

3) НАЙТИ *Вася*, ЗАМЕНИТЬ *1*, *Заменить_все*, *ОК* и т.д.

**Макрос**.

Если диапазоны большие, если работа не разовая - лучше  воспользоваться приведенным ниже кодом для замены значений в столбце *А*. Код разместить в общем модуле. Запускать обработку можно любой фигурой, рисунком etc., назначив им макрос.

```
Sub AssigValue()
Dim aVal(), aTable()
Dim lRw As Long, i As Long, k As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' размер диапазона столбца А'
        aVal = .Range("A1:A" & lRw).Value ' значения в массив'
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row ' размер таблицы'
        aTable = .Range("B1:C" & lRw).Value ' таблица в массив'

        For i = 1 To UBound(aVal) ' по записям столбца А'
            For k = 1 To UBound(aTable) ' по записям таблицы'
                If aVal(i, 1) = aTable(k, 2) Then ' значения совпали'
                    aVal(i, 1) = aTable(k, 1): Exit For ' меняем значение столбца А'
                End If
            Next k
        Next i

        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(aVal), 1) = aVal ' выгружаем массив на лист'
    End With
End Sub
```

Если менять не нужно, но подставить соответствия, массив выгружать в другой столбец (например, с *.Range("D1")*)

Comment: Если ПРОСМОТР - это LOOKUP, то он работает только с отсортированным списком.

Comment: Нет, при такой конструкции не обязательно.

Comment: Хм.. Не обратил внимания на конструкцию... А можно её пояснить?

Comment: Из набора условий получаем массив из ошибок и одной единицы. Ошибки функция игнорирует, ищет 2 (число должно быть больше максимального значения в полученном массиве) . Т.к. двойки нет, определяет позицию последнего числового значения. На этой позиции находит требуемое.